# Video plays from browser but not on Movie player -SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, video, mpmovieplayercontroller, mpmovieplayer

Tired of posting questions on SO about the same problem and still not getting solution..If anyone solves this i am gonna award bounty to user afterwards.

I am trying to play video that is on server.A video from the Url(which is commented) gets played but the other dont.What am i doing wrong??

```
class VideoViewController: UIViewController {

    var moviePlayer:MPMoviePlayerController!

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

        //var url = NSURL(string: "http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/gear1/prog_index.m3u8")
        //playVideoFromURL(url!)

        var url = NSURL(string: "private url")
        playVideoFromURL(url!)

    }

    func playVideoFromURL( address: NSURL ) {

        println(address)
        var playerVC = MPMoviePlayerViewController(contentURL: address)
        playerVC.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.CoverVertical
        self.presentViewController(playerVC, animated: false, completion: nil)
        playerVC.moviePlayer.prepareToPlay()
        playerVC.moviePlayer.play()


    }
}
```

Movie player plays the video of the commented ones but doesnot plays the other.What may be the reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct. All you need is to update your info.plist file by adding this key:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>  
<dict>  
     <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key><true/>  
</dict>
```

Or you can add it another way and it will look like:

[image]

Comment: i am using swift 1.2 and xcode 6.3 both are http request..and does this matter?

Comment: Ahh sorry I didn't realise that you are using swift 1.2. But this code is working fine with swift 2.0. And I don't have Xcode 6.3 so I can not test it. I advise you to update your Xcode.:)

Comment: Yes both videos are playing.

Comment: ok i will update my xcode and try..which device are you testing in?

Comment: I have tested it with simulator. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91718/discussion-between-swift-butcher-and-dharmesh-kheni).